# Find if word exist in array or string PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am trying to find if any of the string inside an array exist in array of words.

For example:

```
$key = ["sun","clouds"];
$results = ["Sun is hot","Too many clouds"];
```

If any of `$key` exists in `$results` to return `true`

With below script I get the result I want but only if word in `$results` is exact like the word in `$key`.

```
function contain($key = [], $results){
    $record_found = false;
    if(is_array($results)){

        // Loop through array
        foreach ($results as $result) {
             $found = preg_match_all("/\b(?:" .join($key, '|'). ")\b/i", $result, $matches);
             if ($found) {
                $record_found = true;
             }
        }

     } else {

         // Scan string to find word
         $found = preg_match_all("/\b(?:" .join($key, '|'). ")\b/i", $results, $matches);
         if ($found) {
            $record_found = true;
         }

      }

      return $record_found;

 }
```

If the word in `$results` is `Enjoy all year round **sunshine**` my function returns `false` as can not find word sun. How can I change my function to return true if string contain that string as part of word?

I want the word `sun` to match even with `sun` or `sunshine`.

TIA

Comment: There is no word boundary `\b` between `sun` and `shine`

Comment: @Thefourthbird i know. The problem is i dont know if the word would be sunshine. That was an example. The $ressults may contain words like sunny,sunshine,sunday etc. is there any way i can change my script to return true or should i contain any possible word inside $key array?

Comment: The trick is: even if this is not an exact duplicate (as in: copy&paste that code), it helps you to solve your problem. Read it, change your code accordingly, and ask when that code still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so as was said you can take the check from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word)
and instead of regex use it + [mb_strtolower](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) in loop:

```
<?php
$keys = ["sun","clouds"];
$results = ["Sun is hot","Too many clouds"];

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    foreach ($results as $result) {     
        if (strpos(mb_strtolower($result), mb_strtolower($key)) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: I just don't even know what else can be added :(